# SVN auto-props are not being set

Tags: windows, svn

I have auto-props in working copy like this

```
c:\TestRepos>svn pg svn:auto-props --verbose
Properties on '.':
   svn:auto-props
      '*=svn:needs-lock=*'
```

but when I add a new file with

```
c:\TestRepos>svn add test/test.txt
```

and commit it

```
c:\TestRepos>svn commit -m "Msg" test/test.txt
```

the needs-lock property wasn't set on the file

```
c:\TestRepos>svn proplist heh\heh.txt

c:\TestRepos>
```

and obviously Read-only attribute wasn't set.

Why don't auto-props work in my case?

Thanks

Comment: what's the client version?

Comment: svn, version 1.9.3 (r1718519)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto properties are disabled by default. To enable it you have to set `enable-auto-props = yes` in Subversion's configuration file usually located in `<application data>\Subversion\config`.

Or you have to call add command with `--auto-props` parameter.

```
c:\TestRepos>svn add --auto-props test/test.txt
```